# Java-how to use annotation in Junit - eclipse

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit, annotations

I am trying to test if a method throws a IllegalArgumentException in Junit with the code below, however it didn't work. Eclipse suggested to create an annotation class, which confuses me a bit. Can I get away without using an annotation? Otherwise what's the best solution for this?

```
  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
      public void testRegister(){
            myProgram.register(-23); //the argument should be positive 
      }
```

Comment: your test code seems to be correct, may be the `method` under `test` ie `register` is not really throwing `IllegalArgumentException` at all. In that case you need to fix the implementation of the `register` method.

Comment: I usually use try-catch, catching the exception I'm interrested in and pass the test in that catch block.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work" what was the problem exactly?

Comment: You might be using junit3. Annotations are available in junit4 only. You can (and probably should) rename test method to something more meaningful if you are using junit4.

Comment: @tobypls can you elaborate on how to use try and catch?

Comment: @user4056620 Added an answer for you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually try catching the Exception I'm interrested in, and pass the test if it's caught. Try something like this:

```
try {
    myProgram.register(-23);
    // (optional) fail test here
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
    // pass test here
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // (optional) fail test here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! do we need to add any code in the catch block, like assert something, or can we just leave it blank?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear about that. I was too lazy to check the syntax for JUnit. Any time that you `return` or `assertTrue(true)`, the test will **pass**. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036144/junit4-fail-is-here-but-where-is-pass) for further info on that. To **fail**, call `fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an annotation you can catch all exceptions and test in an assertion that the exception is of instance IllegalArgumentException.

```
Exception e = null;
try {
  // statement that should cause exception
} catch(Exception exc) {
  e = exc;
}

// Assert that e is not null to make sure an exception was thrown
// Assert that e is of type IllegalARgumentException
```

But in the end it is much simpler to just use the JUnit annotation. Which seems to be correct to me.